# Check multiple values in a column and return value 1 or 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to return 1 if a `user_id` have `status=1` to any of these `product_id 2,3,4` in one MySQL query else return 0

```
Table: user_status

status_id    user_id    product_id    status
---------------------------------------------
1               27        2             1
2               27        3             0
3               27        4             1
4               32        2             1
5               35        4             1
6               40        2             0
7               40        3             1
8               41        2             0
9               41        3             1
10              45        4             0
```

I tried the following query,

```
SELECT status FROM `user_status` WHERE `user_id` = '27'  AND status = '1' AND product_id IN (2,9,11);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EXISTS for your purpose, as it return ture (1) or FALSE (0)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user_status
>     (`status_id` int, `user_id` int, `product_id` int, `status` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO user_status
>     (`status_id`, `user_id`, `product_id`, `status`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 27, 2, 1),
>     (2, 27, 3, 0),
>     (3, 27, 4, 1),
>     (4, 32, 2, 1),
>     (5, 35, 4, 1),
>     (6, 40, 2, 0),
>     (7, 40, 3, 1),
>     (8, 41, 2, 0),
>     (9, 41, 3, 1),
>     (10, 45, 4, 0)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> Exists(SELECT 
>     1
> FROM
>     `user_status`
> WHERE
>     `user_id` = '27' AND status = '1'
>         AND product_id IN (2 , 9, 11)) answer;
> ```

> ```
> 1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> Exists(
> SELECT 
>     1
> FROM
>     `user_status`
> WHERE
>     `user_id` = '49' AND status = '1'
>         AND product_id IN (2 , 9, 11)) answer
> ```

> ```
> 0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7deb351d1e525f71af53b72fe63589a)*

Answer (score 2):

you can use HAVING clause to get the desired results

`select user_id from user_status where product_id in (2,3,4) group by user_id having max(status) =1`